# Remove spacing and vertical align divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the boxes in view:

- touch each other
- vertical align so they all touch the top of the parent div
- keep the slider without JavaScript

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/GDsoy)

I've been trying cell-spacing, vertical-align, border-spacing, and etc. but either I'm not understanding how to apply them or I've gone in a bad direction with the DOM.

[image]

Why in a codepen? I'm building a theme for Bootstrap 2.

Comment: what do you mean "keep the slider without JavaScript"?

Comment: @koala_dev I have a overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll; setup so that I can add as many of those boxes as I want and it scrolls horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a padding applied to the `td` elements, remove that and set `vertical-align: top`.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/thgaskell/pen/Jcdml)

#### CSS

```
td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to isolate this styling via a .module td {}? When I add .module as a parent this styling doesn't work any more.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you show an example?

Comment: http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/dCtxj Making it .module td { padding: 0; vertical-align: top; } breaks that css.

Comment: You need to make `td` a descendent of `.module` in the HTML for it to work.

Comment: I was mistaking `.module` for `.row-slide`. Thank you it works fine now!